# Creating a blurView with a clear cut out

Tags: ios, swift, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I am creating an overlay of blurredView with a clear rectangle cutout in the middle. My code so far has achieved the opposite, ie a clearView with a blur cutout in the middle instead.

I have adapted my steps from the following posts, I appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

[Swift mask of circle layer over UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173116/swift-mask-of-circle-layer-over-uiview)

[CALayer with transparent hole in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512761/calayer-with-transparent-hole-in-it)

```
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
blurView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)

let scanLayer = CAShapeLayer()
scanLayer.path = CGPath(rect: scanRect, transform: nil)

view.addSubview(blurView)
blurView.layer.addSublayer(scanLayer)
blurView.layer.mask = scanLayer
```

Comment: i dont have any idea... but the last line should not be there blurView.layer.mask = scanLayer

Comment: use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647792/swift-how-to-create-a-view-with-a-shape-cropped-in-it see Dănuț Mihai Florian's answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
    let scanLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    let scanRect = CGRect.init(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)

    let outerPath = UIBezierPath(rect: scanRect)

    let superlayerPath = UIBezierPath.init(rect: blurView.frame)
    outerPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
    outerPath.append(superlayerPath)
    scanLayer.path = outerPath.cgPath
    scanLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    scanLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    view.addSubview(blurView)
    blurView.layer.mask = scanLayer
```

Comment: This solution worked! But I don understand the concept. Why is there a need to have superlayerPath?

Comment: Because you need to mask everything around the inner rectangle but not the rectangle itself. You can add this line in order to see how the mask working let superlayerPath = UIBezierPath.init(ovalIn: blurView.frame)

Comment: Thanks great ans.Now i want to add shadow on that cut out area.How can it possible.please help me. @VitalyMigunov

Comment: This is a topic for new question @YogendraPatel